# Functionaly DESKTOP!

Tags: desktop

Everything is fine except the desktop!
no shortcuts, no folders. Why is it needed at all? make it normal and functional!
only takes up space on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Polikarp you can set the desktop icon envioriment with this app

[image: Download Desktop Folder by DesktopFolder Developers in Accesories ~ Elementary OS Store]

Answer (score 0):

This has been explained many times before, this is a design choice, to keep the desktop uncluttered and to make users to really use the different folders that exist on your home folder.

If you desire to use it to put files you can use the "Desktop folder" app on the app center.